# Implement Perl's unpack method functionality in Java

Tags: java

I have Perl code that I want to convert to Java.

I have an array of bytes with at least 48 elements. Starting at position 44 is a 32-bit signed integer using the local machine's byte order. I would like these bytes unpacked into an `int`.

For those that knowing Perl, the value can be obtained in Perl using the following:

```
my $SATsizeSectors = unpack("l", substr($header, 44, 4));
```

I am using the following code, but it's give me wrong output:

```
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(binaryData.getBytes());
byte[] bArr = new byte[4]; 
int bytesRead = is.read(bArr);
ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.wrap(bArr);
resultData = buf.getInt();
```

Comment: The `pack`/`unpack` function pair is well-documented in http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html . What code have you written already and how does it fail to work for you? Most likely you will have to read the data into a `byte[]` and then rearrange/cast/compute the results according to the `pack` template. Note that you cannot mimic the Perl code as Java will want far more types than Perl uses for such cases.

Comment: I don't know of a drop-in library that understands all formats. You'll have to implement the patterns that you need. How does your `$v` look like?

Comment: How wrong is your output? Note that a Java `int` is signed. Also there is byte order to consider.

Comment: The Perl code skips the first 44 bytes in `$header`. Do you have any not shown Java code that does that?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using streams, `DataInputStream` is the one you want.

```
byte[] header = ...;

DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(header));
dis.skipBytes(44);
int SATsizeSectors = dis.readInt();
```

But it might be far simpler to simply use the following:

```
byte[] header = ...;

int SATsizeSectors = ( ( header[47] >> 8 | header[46] ) >> 8 | header[45] ) >> 8 | header[44];
```